# Akka streams: Reading multiple files

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a list of files. I want:

1. To read from all of them as a single Source.
2. Files should be read sequentially, in-order. (no round-robin)
3. At no point should any file be required to be entirely in memory.
4. An error reading from a file should collapse the stream.

It felt like this should work: (Scala, akka-streams v2.4.7)

```
val sources = Seq("file1", "file2").map(new File(_)).map(f => FileIO.fromPath(f.toPath)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(bs => bs.utf8String)
  )
val source = sources.reduce( (a, b) => Source.combine(a, b)(MergePreferred(_)) )
source.map(_ => 1).runWith(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _)) // counting lines
```

But that results in a compile error since `FileIO` has a materialized value associated with it, and `Source.combine` doesn't support that.

Mapping the materialized value away makes me wonder how file-read errors get handled, but does compile:

```
val sources = Seq("file1", "file2").map(new File(_)).map(f => FileIO.fromPath(f.toPath)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(bs => bs.utf8String)
    .mapMaterializedValue(f => NotUsed.getInstance())
  )
val source = sources.reduce( (a, b) => Source.combine(a, b)(MergePreferred(_)) )
source.map(_ => 1).runWith(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _))  // counting lines
```

But throws an IllegalArgumentException at runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [MergePreferred.out] must correspond to the inlets [MergePreferred.preferred] and outlets [MergePreferred.out]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code below is not as terse as it could be, in order to clearly modularize the different concerns.

```
// Given a stream of bytestrings delimited by the system line separator we can get lines represented as Strings
val lines = Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000, allowTruncation = true).map(bs => bs.utf8String)

// given as stream of Paths we read those files and count the number of lines
val lineCounter = Flow[Path].flatMapConcat(path => FileIO.fromPath(path).via(lines)).fold(0l)((count, line) => count + 1).toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)

// Here's our test data source (replace paths with real paths)
val testFiles = Source(List("somePathToFile1", "somePathToFile2").map(new File(_).toPath))

// Runs the line counter over the test files, returns a Future, which contains the number of lines, which we then print out to the console when it completes
testFiles runWith lineCounter foreach println
```

Comment: I was looking for modular, so I appreciate that. I was using line count as an example of something I could do with the files, and `lineCounter` as written conflates that with the file reading. (It's a Sink) But if I move the fold and everything after it elsewhere, I'm left with a Flow[Path,String, NotUsed], which is exactly the piece I was looking for.

Comment: Could you please provide imports with your examples, they are an essential part of the code.

Comment: @OsskarWerrewka It should all be in akka.stream.scaladsl and java IO/NIO. Did you have a problem with it?

Comment: I finally did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** Oh, I didn't see the accepted answer because I didn't refresh the page >_<. I'll leave this here anyway since I've also added some notes about error handling.

I believe the following program does what you want:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, IOResult}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Flow, Framing, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import java.nio.file.Paths
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object TestMain extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit def ec = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val sources = Vector("build.sbt", ".gitignore")
    .map(Paths.get(_))
    .map(p =>
      FileIO.fromPath(p)
        .viaMat(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator()), Int.MaxValue, allowTruncation = true))(Keep.left)
        .mapMaterializedValue { f =>
          f.onComplete {
            case Success(r) if r.wasSuccessful => println(s"Read ${r.count} bytes from $p")
            case Success(r) => println(s"Something went wrong when reading $p: ${r.getError}")
            case Failure(NonFatal(e)) => println(s"Something went wrong when reading $p: $e")
          }
          NotUsed
        }
    )
  val finalSource = Source(sources).flatMapConcat(identity)

  val result = finalSource.map(_ => 1).runWith(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _))
  result.onComplete {
    case Success(n) => println(s"Read $n lines total")
    case Failure(e) => println(s"Reading failed: $e")
  }
  Await.ready(result, 10.seconds)

  actorSystem.terminate()
}
```

The key here is the [`flatMapConcat()`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@flatMapConcat[T,M](f:Out=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[T],M]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) method: it transforms each element of a stream into a source and returns a stream of elements yielded by these sources if they are run sequentially.

As for handling errors, you can either add a handler to the future in the `mapMaterializedValue` argument, or you can handle the final error of the running stream by putting a handler on the `Sink.foreach` materialized future value. I did both in the example above, and if you test it, say, on a nonexisting file, you'll see that the same error message will be printed twice. Unfortunately, `flatMapConcat()` does not collect materialized values, and frankly I can't see the way it could do it sanely, therefore you have to handle them separately, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I do have one answer out of the gate - don't use `akka.FileIO`. This appears to work fine, for example:

```
val sources = Seq("sample.txt", "sample2.txt").map(io.Source.fromFile(_).getLines()).reduce(_ ++ _)
val source = Source.fromIterator[String](() => sources)
val lineCount = source.map(_ => 1).runWith(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _))
```

I'd still like to know whether there's a better solution.

Comment: By using `io.Source` you lose lot of power. For small files this might work but it is not an option for large ones.

Comment: @jarandaf Can you clarify? I was under the impression that io.Source just used a BufferedReader under the hood, and the getLines iterator does not load the whole file at once or anything like that.

Comment: better thought, you might be right (although `FileIO` handles `ByteString` instead of `String`, which is meant to be more performant). On the other hand, with `io.Source` one always has to keep in mind to close the source (which is not done by default).

Comment: The `sources` name above is wrong, isn't it? Before the `.reduce(_ ++ _)` it is sources, but after that (the actual value) is a single `Iterator[String]`, representing all the files, already merged. Just a naming issue - liked the code!

Comment: Yeah, I could see that. I meant sources in the semantic sense of "containing many sources", but you're right that it's a single Iterator variable, not a list, which could be confusing.