# Reading multiple files with akka streams in scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'am trying to read multiple files with akka streams and put result in a list.
I can read one file with no problem. the return type is Future[Seq[String]]. problem is processing the sequence inside the Future must go inside an onComplete{}.

i'am trying the following code but abviously it will not work. the list acc outside of the onComplete is empty. but holds values inside the inComplete. I understand the problem but i don't know how to approach this.

```
// works fine  
def readStream(path: String, date: String): Future[Seq[String]] = {
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
val settings = ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(settings)

val result: Future[Seq[String]] =
  FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(path + "transactions_" + date + 
".data"))
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
    .run()
 var aa: List[scala.Array[String]] = Nil
 result.onComplete(x => {
  aa = x.get.map(line => line.split('|')).toList
})
 result
}

//this won't work  
def concatFiles(path : String, date : String, numberOfDays : Int) : 
List[scala.Array[String]] = {
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
val formattedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
var acc = List[scala.Array[String]]()

for( a <- 0 to numberOfDays){
  val date = formattedDate.minusDays(a).toString().replace("-", "")


  val transactions = readStream(path , date)
  var result: List[scala.Array[String]] = Nil
  transactions.onComplete(x => {
    result = x.get.map(line => line.split('|')).toList 
    acc=  acc ++ result })
}
acc}
```

Comment: Stay within akka:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/flatMapConcat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Akka streams: Reading multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799927/akka-streams-reading-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General Solution**

Given an Iterator of `Paths` values a `Source` of the file lines can be created by combining [`FileIO`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) & [`flatMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/flatMapConcat.html#flatmapconcat):

```
val lineSourceFromPaths : (() => Iterator[Path]) => Source[String, _] = pathsIterator =>
  Source
    .fromIterator(pathsIterator)
    .flatMapConcat { path =>
      FileIO
        .fromPath(path)
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true))
        .map(_.utf8String)
    }
```

**Application to Question**

The reason your `List` is empty is because the `Future` values have not completed and therefore your mutable list is not be updated before the function returns the list.

**Critique of Code in Question**

The organization and style of the code within the question suggest several misunderstandings related to `akka` & `Future`.  I think you are attempting a rather complex workflow without understanding the fundamentals of the tools you are trying to use.

1.You should not create an `ActorSystem` each time a function is being called.  There is usually 1 ActorSystem per application and it's created only once.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
val settings = ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(settings)

def readStream(...
```

2.You should try to avoid mutable collections and instead use `Iterator` with corresponding functionality:

```
def concatFiles(path : String, date : String, numberOfDays : Int) : List[scala.Array[String]] = {

  val formattedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))

  val pathsIterator : () => Iterator[Path] = () => 
    Iterator
      .range(0, numberOfDays+1)
      .map(formattedDate.minusDays)
      .map(_.String().replace("-", "")
      .map(path => Paths.get(path + "transactions_" + date + ".data")

  lineSourceFromPaths(pathsIterator)
```

3.Since you are dealing with Futures you should not wait for Futures to complete and should instead change the return type of `concateFiles` to `Future[List[Array[String]]]`.